# Error ionic - cordova installation

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, npm

I'm trying to launch ionic and cordova on Ubuntu 14.04 but occur this error:

```
module.js:327
throw err;
^


Error: Cannot find module 'bplist-parser'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/cordova-common/src/ConfigChanges/ConfigFile.js:20:14)
at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
```

Anyone know how to solve this?
I'm using node v4.4.0, npm 3.8.0

Thanks!

Comment: Try npm install -g bplist-parser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your system need some more modules. Try install missed modules:

```
sudo npm install -g bplist-parser
```

and you can refer to this ionic forum error post:https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/error-cannot-find-module-bplist-parser/38551

Answer (score 0):

Try install bplist-parser:

```
sudo npm install -g bplist-parser
```

And it seems that you have some components not be installed, so maybe other error tips will come out because of missing components. Just install them like above command.
Hope this will help you , if not, could you describe when you encounter this problem? Sorry for I could not figure out what's the meaning of *launch ionic and cordova*.